# how to insert file into table?

Tags: php, mysqli

code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["add"]))
{
    extract($_POST);
    $filename = $_FILES['ad']['name'];
    $path = "../../ads";
    $move=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ad']['tmp_name'],$path.$_FILES['ad']['name']);
    $sql2="insert into advertisement(ad,priority)values('$filename','$priority')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql2);
    if($result == true)
    {
        $msg .= "<h5 style='color:green;'>Successfull</h5>";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg .= "<h5 style='color:red;'>Error</h5>";
    }
}
?>
```

html code:

```
<form method="POST" >
<input type='file' name="ad" id="ad" />         
<select name="priority" id="priority">
    <option value="">Select Priority</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>   
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

In this code when I click on submit button only priority value insert into database while ad or file is not inserting. what is the problem in this code ? and How can I fix this problem ?

Thank You

Comment: You do no error checking in your code. How do you expect to handle errors if you don't look for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to the form tag. Validate your input before inserting it into the database. Don't use extract function.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link to upload files in `PHP`.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

it's simple
Add enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to the form tag. Validate your input before inserting it into the database. Don't use extract function.